# Sorting based on one of many related entities

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

Entity B (Book) has a one-to-many relationship with the entity D (Description). The idea is that a book has different descriptions for different languages.

I want to sort books based on their titles (D.title) for a given language (D.languageID)

If B had one-to-one relationship to D, I would do something like:

```m
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"d.title" ascending:YES];
```

Of course, you may say, the model does not prevent a book from having many descriptions with the same languageID. But in this case any (e.g. the first) description would be ok for me.

Is my model wrong? What's the best solution now?

Answer (score 0):

This is logically not possible. If you have many objects B belonging to A, which B is the sort routine supposed to take?

For example you have the entity A "Parent" and the entity B "Child" and the attribute of B "dateOfBirth". You cannot sort all Parent objects according to the lowest birth date because if two different parents have two children each, it is possible that each of them has a child that is older than one of the other's.

Clear?

Comment: I know in advance which object B has to be used. So that is my question, how can I sort Parent objects according to a specific Child object?

Comment: I don't see what is illogical about sorting parents according to the lowest birth date of any of their childs

Comment: I see your point. You have to first determine the youngest child of each parent and then extract and sort. Not sure on how to do this in one simple fetch. It is not too difficult with a loop.

Comment: what if you want to sort by the relationship.@max.date ? how would you do that then ? here you have a definitive single value from the collection of one-to-many relationship that you can actually sort by

Comment: 1) fetch all parents; 2) loop and strip all but oldest child; 3) sort by child.date.